# Migrate Microsoft Test Manager Tests from TFS2015 to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

Can nkdagility be used to convert Microsoft Test Manager Test to Azure DevOps?  If not what is the suggested path for conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: the Azure DevOps Migration Tools support this with many caviats.